# Set plugin order when installing

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin

During plugin installation, is it possible to set it to be always the last one in its group?
Thanks

Comment: Is this for a custom plugin you are writing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to have a [installer script](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file). Then in the install script do something like:

```
public function postflight($route, $_this)
{
    // Get a database connector object
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    try {
        // Enable plugin by default
        $q = $db->getQuery(true);

        $q->update('#__extensions');
        $q->set($this->db->quoteName('ordering') . ' = -1')
            ->where($this->db->quoteName('type') . ' = ' . $this->db->quote('plugin'))
            ->where($this->db->quoteName('element') . ' = ' . $this->db->quote('PLUGIN_NAME'))
            ->where($this->db->quoteName('folder') . ' = ' . $this->db->quote('system'));

        $db->setQuery($q);

        method_exists($db, 'execute') ? $db->execute() : $db->query();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```